# How do I set a variable properly to be tested in a boolean?

Tags: java, methods, initialization, boolean, logic

In my class, we are assigned a CodeHS assignment called Battleship. I'm stuck on part 2 of 7, the Location class. The exercise is as follows:

The next class to write is the Location.java file. The Location class stores the information for one grid position.

A location has two defining attributes

1) Is there a ship at this location?

2) What is the status of this location?

The status of this would be whether this position is unguessed, we got a hit, or got a miss.

```
public static final int UNGUESSED = 0;
public static final int HIT = 1;
public static final int MISSED = 2;
```

These are the methods you will need to implement for the Location class.

```
// Location constructor. 
public Location()

// Was this Location a hit?
public boolean checkHit()

// Was this location a miss?
public boolean checkMiss()

// Was this location unguessed?
public boolean isUnguessed()

// Mark this location a hit.
public void markHit()

// Mark this location a miss.
public void markMiss()

// Return whether or not this location has a ship.
public boolean hasShip()

// Set the value of whether this location has a ship.
public void setShip(boolean val)

// Set the status of this Location.
public void setStatus(int status)

// Get the status of this Location.
public int getStatus()
```

And my work is as follows:

```
public class Location
{
    private int location;
    private int hit;
    private int miss;
    private boolean val;
    private int status;
    //Implement the Location class here
    public static final int UNGUESSED = 0;
    public static final int HIT = 1;
    public static final int MISSED = 2;

    // Location constructor. 
    public Location(int location){
        this.location = location;
    }

// Was this Location a hit?
public boolean checkHit(){
    if(location == HIT)
    return true;
    return false;
}

// Was this location a miss?
public boolean checkMiss(){
    if(location == MISSED)
    return true;
    return false;
}

// Was this location unguessed?
public boolean isUnguessed(){
    if(location == UNGUESSED)
    return true;
    return false;
}

// Mark this location a hit.
public void markHit(int hit){
    this.hit = hit;
}

// Mark this location a miss.
public void markMiss(int miss){
    this.miss = miss;
}

// Return whether or not this location has a ship.
public boolean hasShip(){
    return val;
}

    // Set the value of whether this location has a ship.
   public void setShip(boolean val){
    if(status == HIT)
    val = true;
    else 
    val = false;
}

// Set the status of this Location.
public void setStatus(int status){
    this.status = status;
}

// Get the status of this Location.
public int getStatus(){
    if(status == HIT)
    return HIT;
    else if (status == MISSED)
    return MISSED;
    else if(status == UNGUESSED)
    return UNGUESSED;
}

}
```

While I really wouldn't be surprised if I have errors elsewhere, my main problem is the setShip Boolean method. How am I supposed to set it to true (there is a ship in that position) or false (there is no ship). What I have was my best guess, but that only is true if tested after the "shot". And I think the exercise wants it to be tested before that.

Comment: 1) Should the location be a `Point` (x,y)? 2) the field `val` should be changed to mean `hasShip` 3) If you used the setter/getter functionality you would see that you should just set and get the `hasShip` value 4) consider `public boolean checkHit () {return localtion == HIT);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Don't change the method-signatures you got from the exercise (e.g. the constructor shouldn't have a parameter, same goes for the `markHit` and `markMiss` methods.

You don't need to save your `int miss` and `int hit` in two different variables since a location can't be hit and missed at the same time, we therefore use a single variable `status`.

I'm pretty sure your question 1 and 2 are (more or less) the same thing since there's a ship if there's a hit and vice versa so you would only have an attribute `int status = 0` so each location is `UNCHECKED` per default and you can read everything from there.

All you then have to do is to change the status variable on the `markMiss`and `markHit` methods and call `setShip` accordingly.

Code example:

```
public void markMiss() {
    this.status = MISSED;
    setShip(false);
}

public void markHit() {
    this.status = HIT;
    setShip(true);
}

public boolean checkMiss() {
    return this.status == MISSED;
}

public boolean checkHit() {
    return this.status == HIT;
}

public boolean setShip(boolean val) {
    this.hasAShip = val;
}

public boolean hasShip() {
    return this.hasAShip;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys. Using the feedback provided, I fixed the class to the following and it now works.

```
public class Location
{
    private int status;
    private boolean ship;
    //Implement the Location class here
    public static final int UNGUESSED = 0;
    public static final int HIT = 1;
    public static final int MISSED = 2;

    // Location constructor. 
    public Location(){
        status = UNGUESSED;
        ship = false;
    }

    // Was this Location a hit?
    public boolean checkHit(){
        if(status == HIT)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Was this location a miss?
    public boolean checkMiss(){
        if(status == MISSED)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Was this location unguessed?
    public boolean isUnguessed(){
        if(status == UNGUESSED)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Mark this location a hit.
    public void markHit(){
        status = HIT;
    }

    // Mark this location a miss.
    public void markMiss(){
        status = MISSED;
    }

    // Return whether or not this location has a ship.
    public boolean hasShip(){
        return ship;
    }

    // Set the value of whether this location has a ship.
    public void setShip(boolean val){
        ship = val;
    }

    // Set the status of this Location.
    public void setStatus(int status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    // Get the status of this Location.
    public int getStatus(){
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks better, although be aware that it only works because int is 0 per default if not initialized. Also your methods are unnecessary large, you can just return status == UNGUESSED instead of if(status == UNGUESSED) return true; else return false; which does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a private boolean val that you return with hasShip().

Your setShip(val) method should set the class variable with val, not calculate something based on stats.

It's just a simple setter method.

EDIT:

It's just like

```
// Mark this location a hit.
public void markHit(int hit){
    this.hit = hit;
}
```